# How do I make an object move to a certain location when the player looks at it? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to have an eyeball that when the player looks at, it disappears by moving to the side. Like in a horror game. I know how to make the object move to a set location but I don't know how I would make the object do the action when the player looks at it.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) to detect the position that the player is looking at.

For example (this code uses the screen center position as looking position)

```cs
void LookingObject(){
    // The object requires Rigidbody and Collider to work

    float lookDistance = 500.0f;

    // 0.5f means it's the center... Screen varies from 0 as bottom and 1 as top
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0));

    // Draw ray only instantiates a ray in viewport, not on game - Not required to work
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * lookDistance, Color.red);

    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, lookDistance)){
        if(hit.transform.CompareTag("TAG")){
            // If object tag is TAG - Do your thing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just want to make sure that I understand the script. Ray ray = Cam... makes the 'look ray' be set to the middle of screen.
Then if (physics... makes it so it detects if it has hit something
and if(hit.transform... means if that specific object is is in the ray then the action happens?

Comment: ````Ray```` creates an infinite line from one point to a direction. The ````if()```` takes every object that was hit by the ray (with a maximum distance) and do your logic to the object